# how to enable summaries only for selected rows in xamdatagrid?

Tags: wpf, xaml, infragistics, xamdatagrid

I am working on a wpf application using the infragistices grid.I searched the infragistics forums,googled and did not find anything, I did find that the devExpress grid does support [this](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q93136.aspx), but could not find similar solution for the infragistics counterpart

I am trying to see if there is a way to enable the summary to work only when the rows are selected by the user ? any help in how to get this to work would be appreciated
has anybody tried any such conditional summary calculations

Answer (score 1):

if your grid is in the variable `dataGrid`, this LINQ should work

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a readonly list of the filtered selected records.
    /// </summary>
    public IList<DataRecord> SelectedRecords
    {
        get
        {
            return dataGrid.Records.Cast<DataRecord>().Where(r => r.IsFilteredOut != true && r.IsSelected && !r.IsDeleted).ToList().AsReadOnly();
        }
    }
```